# Modifying a QuickSort to work with a Fraction class, running into StackOverFlow error

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, fractions

Fraction class:

```
public class Fraction 
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction()
    {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {   
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if(numerator == 0)
        {
            String str = "0";
            return str;
        }
        else if((numerator % denominator) == 0)
        {
            int num = (numerator / denominator);
            String str = "" + num;
            return str;
        }
        else if(numerator > denominator)
        {
            int whole = 0;
            int remainder = numerator;

            while(remainder > denominator)
            {
                remainder -= denominator;
                whole++;
            }

            String str = whole + " " + asFraction(remainder,denominator);
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            String str = asFraction(numerator,denominator);
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static long GCM(long a, long b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : GCM(b, a % b);
    }

    public static String asFraction(long a, long b) {
        long GCM = GCM(a, b);
        return (a / GCM) + "/" + (b / GCM);
    }

    public int getNumerator() 
    {
        return numerator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int numerator) 
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() 
    {
        return denominator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int denominator) 
    {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
}
```

QuickSort class:

```
public class FractionalQuickSort 
{

    private Fraction array[];
    private int length;

    public void sort(Fraction[] inputArr) 
    {   
        if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) 
        {
            return;
        }
        this.array = inputArr;
        length = inputArr.length;
        fractionalQuickSort(0, length - 1);
    }

    private void fractionalQuickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) 
    {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;

        Fraction pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];

        while (i <= j) 
        {
            while (compareFractions(array[i], pivot) == false) 
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (compareFractions(pivot, array[j]) == false) 
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) 
            {
                exchangeNumbers(i, j);

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        if (lowerIndex < j)
        {
            fractionalQuickSort(lowerIndex, j);
        }
        if (i < higherIndex)
        {
            fractionalQuickSort(i, higherIndex);
        }
    }

    private boolean compareFractions(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
        int valueOne = ( a.getNumerator() * b.getDenominator() );
        int valueTwo = ( a.getDenominator() * b.getNumerator() );

        if (valueOne > valueTwo)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) 
    {
        Fraction temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class FractionalQuickSortDriver
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        FractionalQuickSort sorter = new FractionalQuickSort();

        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(0,3);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(10,2);
        Fraction f3 = new Fraction(3,4);
        Fraction f4 = new Fraction(12,20);
        Fraction f5 = new Fraction(22,5);
        Fraction f6 = new Fraction(1,6);
        Fraction f7 = new Fraction(3,8);
        Fraction f8 = new Fraction(2,6);

        Fraction[] input = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8};
        sorter.sort(input);
        for(Fraction i:input)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a quick sort I found that I am trying to implement with a Fraction class that I've written. The quick sort itself works fine when using integers, I've tested it several times with randomized input and it was clearly written by someone smarter than me. I am trying to modify it to work with fractions, but running into a stackoverflow error when the `fractionlQuickSort` tries to call itself.

I put in some simple printline statements to try and debug it, and from my limited understanding (still learning) there seems to be an issue with the index. I placed a printline statement after the pivot is declared, and every single time (until the error is thrown) the pivot comes out to the same value, 1/3. The sorting algorithm is also repeating the same comparisons, which tells me it is stuck in a loop without the index going anywhere, or it is calling itself improperly. I believe my `compareFractions` method is correct and not the issue since printlines after each comparison was made confirmed it was doing them all properly (i.e. 0 was less than 1/3, 1/6 was less than 1/3, etc.). I'm a bit at a loss now for what the problem might be after trying and failing to fix what I thought the issue could be for the past few hours. I would greatly appreciate some people smarter than me looking at my code and nudging me in the right direction.

EDIT: Not sure why this works, but a few minutes after posting this question, I made the following change to my `compareFractions` method as a last ditch effort...

```
    if (valueOne > valueTwo)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (valueOne < valueTwo)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (valueOne == valueTwo)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

...and the program now works fine, and as an added bonus the array is actually sorted in order. I'd be lying if I said I knew why this fixed it, so I would still appreciate someone explaining what was going on with my code.

Comment: What's "GCM"? Greatest Common Multiple? Wouldn't that be infinity in every case? You mean GCD, Greatest Common Divisor, don't you?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It is supposed to be GCD, you're correct, but it functions the way it's supposed to despite the name. It is used when printing fractions so something like 2/4 gets printed as 1/2, and so on. It functions correctly, as far as I've tested it, and it's not involved in the sorting method itself so I don't think it should be causing any issues.